# Goal- Realm Sync Session Disconnecting after 5 minutes it takes 2 minutes to reconnect again

Tags: android, realm, androidx, realm-mobile-platform

Goal- Maintain Sync Session 
Andriod Gradle Settigs: androidx , Realm Lib-5.12.0,Gradle 3.4.1 
issue facing: Partial Realm Sync Session disconnecting after each 5 mnt , it takes 2 minutes to reconnect again with Realm Cloud Server

I am hitting after each 20 second to realm file for just maintain connection session wake up , i am doing this on Thread

```
SyncManager.refreshConnections();  // it not work for me 


syncTimer=new Timer();
       syncTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               try {
                   if(LoopHealthApplicationClass.getInstance().physicianUser!=null && LoopHealthApplicationClass.getInstance().physicianUser.getPhysicianId()!=null) {
                       boolean chatBoolean=ChatSyncDao.addChatSyncAt(LoopHealthApplicationClass.getInstance().physicianUser.getPhysicianId());
                       boolean userBoolean=SyncDao.addUserSyncAt(LoopHealthApplicationClass.getInstance().physicianUser.getPhysicianId());
                       Timber.d("chatRealm: "+chatBoolean+" | userRealm: "+userBoolean+"| SyncAt");
                   }
               }catch(Exception e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                   SyncManager.refreshConnections(); //Refresh Connection
               }
           }
       }, 20000, 20000);
```

I want to maintain Realm Sync session if it disconnect it should auto connect or some code which i can use to reconnect with cloud sync.

Comment: I doubt you are supposed to manually invoke `SyncManager.refreshConnections()` so many times, are you sure this is needed?

Comment: I really don't know is needed or not, because SyncManager.refreshConnections() is not working for me. i thought refreshConnections will at-least reconnect session to cloud.